# How to control implementation of [dependent generic interfaces]

Tags: c#

*Please read 2nd Edition first.*

---

Let's suppose that we have two dependent generic interfaces:

```
interface ITemplate1<T1, T2>
    where T1 : ITemplate1<T1, T2>
    where T2 : ITemplate2<T1, T2>
{
    T2 t2 { get; set; }
}

interface ITemplate2<T1, T2>
    where T1 : ITemplate1<T1, T2>
    where T2 : ITemplate2<T1, T2>
{
    T1 t1 { get; set; }
}
```

And from both of them two different classes have been implemented:

```
class Class1_1 : ITemplate1<Class1_1, Class2_1>
{
    public Class2_1 t2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Class1_2 : ITemplate1<Class1_2, Class2_2>
{
    public Class2_2 t2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Class2_1 : ITemplate2<Class1_1, Class2_1>
{
    public Class1_1 t1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Class2_2 : ITemplate2<Class1_2, Class2_2>
{
    public Class1_2 t1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to define a class which implement `ITemplate1` regardless of its required types..

```
class MyClass<T> where T : ITemplate1< ? , ? >
{
    ...
}
```

..to prevent from declaring more than one class as:

```
class MyClass1<T> where T : ITemplate1<Class1_1, Class2_1>
{
    ...
}


class MyClass2<T> where T : ITemplate1<Class1_2, Class2_2>
{
    ...
}
```

How can I achieve that? (i.e. Real problem may involved in more than two classes!)
Thanks in advance.

---

**1st Edition:**
`Class1_1` & `Class2_1` as well as `Class1_2` & `Class2_2` must be used together. In other words, I'm looking for a way to have:

```
class MyClass<T>
    where T : ITemplate1<Class1_1, Class2_1>
    or
    where T : ITemplate1<Class1_2, Class2_2>
{
    ...
}
```

---

**2nd Edition:**
I think I could ask this question simpler to avoid to put dear readers into inconvenience. So I do apologize if I mixed you up. The reason for asking such a confusing question is that the real problem is completely complicated. Any way, here is the simple form:

*Title:*
How to control implementation of interfaces?

*Descriptions:*
I have a class which implements two dependent interfaces. I need to control given types, because only some pair of types are consistent with each other. --> *1st Edition*

Comment: Hi, you can try something like MyClass<T,T1,T2> where T : ITemplate1<T1,T2> and add ITemplate1's constraints for T1,T2 but I think you will rather early reach the limitations on the generics system

Comment: the last example you gave together with your won Class1_1, ... definitions compiles ... what's the problem then?

Comment: The problem is that we have not an `or` statement in C# yet!

Comment: oh I see, but why can't you use my ClassBoth_xy example from below? If you really need to constraint it to either case then make two sealed classes with yet another interface or base class?

Comment: BTW: I don't think you will ever see a "or" statement in the generic constraints - just think of all the mischief you could do with

Comment: Would you mind explaining more about your idea about using sealed classes? Thanks.

Comment: make an implementation for your first case and one for your second case. Seal your classes if you don't want anyone from doing his/her own stuff - BTW: I see no point in that but I don't know why you want to implement MyClass with respect to the concrete classes Class1_1, .. too. As I said without you telling me what you really want to achieve it's rather hard to give good advice

Comment: I found the answer but `StackOverflow` doesn't allow me to post it now!
Using `ClassBoth_xy<T1, T2>` is really a good idea but can not restrict `MyClass` from being implemented by incorrect pairs of `<T1, T2>`. I solved this issue using `new()` statement right after `where` clause. Therefore I could instantiate given `T1` & `T2` types in the `MyClass` constructor to check whether they have proper consistency with each other. I'll post the answer later. Thank you @Carsten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ClassBoth_xy<T1, T2>` is a really good idea but can not restrict `MyClass` from being implemented by incorrect pairs of `<T1, T2>`. I solved this issue as:

```
class MyClass<T1, T2>
    where T1 : ITemplate1<T1, T2>, new()
    where T2 : ITemplate2<T1, T2>, new()
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        T1 _t1 = new T1();
        T2 _t2 = new T2();

        bool isValid = (_t1 is Class1_1 && _t2 is Class2_1) ||
                       (_t1 is Class1_2 && _t2 is Class2_2);

        if( !isValid )
            throw new Exception("Inconsistent types have been used to instantiate MyClass.");
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know excactly if you are searching for exactly this, but you can make your ClassX_y more generic for example like:

```
    class Class1_x<T2> : ITemplate1<Class1_x<T2>, T2>
        where T2 : ITemplate2<Class1_x<T2>, T2>
    {
        public T2 t2
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    class Class2_x<T1> : ITemplate2<T1, Class2_x<T1>>
        where T1 : ITemplate1<T1, Class2_x<T1>>
    {
        public T1 t1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Or something like this:

```
class Class1_xy<T1,T2> : ITemplate1<T1,T2>
    where T2 : ITemplate2<T1,T2>
    where T1 : ITemplate1<T1,T2>
{
    public T2 t2
    {
        get; set; }
}

class Class2_xy<T1, T2> : ITemplate2<T1, T2>
    where T2 : ITemplate2<T1, T2>
    where T1 : ITemplate1<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 t1
    { get; set; }
}

class ClassBoth_xy<T1, T2> : ITemplate1<T1,T2>, ITemplate2<T1, T2>
    where T2 : ITemplate2<T1, T2>
    where T1 : ITemplate1<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 t1
    { get; set; }

    public T2 t2
    { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't see exactly the point in this - maybe you can enlighten us?

Comment: Hi @Carsten, thanks but I need more restriction as I described in the edition section.

Comment: Hi - you lost me there - you can do this right away (maybe I get confused by all the 1_2, 2_1, 2_2, ... can't you give some real world example of what you wan't to achieve?